# Python: Sending an email with attachement

Tags: python, email, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am working on a project with a raspberry pi 3 which makes a photo when something is moving. Now I want to send an email with this photo as an attachement.

I already have a code but it tooks 30 seconds to send the mail.
The code I have so far is:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Bewegung erkannt!'+' '+timestr
msg['From'] = 'surveillance.picam@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'fuchsfan23@gmail.com'

body = email.mime.Text.MIMEText("""Bewegung erkannt! Hier ist der Eindrinling!""")
msg.attach(body)

directory = '/home/pi/Pictures/RaspCam/bild_{}.jpg'.format(timestr)

spl_dir=directory.split('/')

filename=spl_dir[len(spl_dir)-1]

spl_type=directory.split('.')

type=spl_type[len(spl_type)-1]
fp=open(directory,'rb')
att = email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(fp.read(),_subtype=type)
fp.close()
att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=filename)
msg.attach(att)

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
s.starttls()
s.login('mailaddress1','passwd')
s.sendmail('mailaddress1','mailaddress2', msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

This code is within an callback which makes the photo when something is moving and saves it.

I hope someone can help me...
CrypticEagle

Comment: Is the issue that it took 30 seconds to send? Are you sure that was strictly sending time, or could that also include receiving time? What are the resolution and filetype of your image?

Comment: @ZachGates The problem is that it really takes 30 seconds to send the mail, because at the end of this script I build in an outpost which says "mail is sended". Between capturing the photo and this outpost are 30 seconds. The filetype is a jpeg but I don't really know about the resolution.

Comment: If the resource size is the cause for your congestion, you could try sending a link to it instead of the whole thing.

Comment: @BoboDarph That's a nice idea, but how do I do this?

Comment: Well I assume your main application already captures and stores the images somewhere. All you would need to do is create a simple FTP or HTTP server and have your code construct a resource location that points to the image and append it to the email as text. Then your client can access that location and retrieve the main photo. Another approach would be to resize your photo to a thumbnail and add that instead of the big picture.

Comment: I think BoboDarph's solution is a good one. You could also send the email in a separate thread so that the main thread can continue execution.